# Extract LSB from integer in assembly x86-64 At&t

Tags: assembly, x86-64, att

I am trying to extract the LSB from an integer in assembly. I know you can bit shift left and right, however I have not found how you can just get the LSB of some integer.

Suppose %rdi stores 13

```
00...00001101
            ^
```

How do I extract the last 1?

Comment: An obvious answer is to use math, so modulus by 2 and that will work in a wide variety of number bases and remainders, though masking is more efficient for powers of 2.  We can also shift twice, so shift left to let bits fall off the other end then shift right to return the number to being right justified.

Comment: What do you want to do with the result?  The `and` suggestions are correct in that they give you the value of the bit as a register set to either 0 or 1, but if you want to do something specific with the bit (conditionally jump based on it, mask another value with it, etc) then there may be better ways to do that.

Answer (score 1):

You can use bitwise AND operation to extract some bits from integers.

For example, to retrieve the LSB of `%rdi` to `%rax`, you can do:

```
mov %rdi, %rax
and $1, %rax
```

Comment: You don't need to copy the high 32 bits.  `mov %edi, %eax; and $1, %eax` is more efficient.  Or `test $1, %dil` ; `setnz %al` if you already had the rest of RAX zeroed.

Answer (score 1):

Perform a bitwise `and` operation with an immediate of 1.

```
and $1, %rdi
```

This sets `%rdi` to just its last bit.

Comment: Can be optimized to `and $1, %edi` of course :)